# rails multiple json representations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

using rails:

1. What's the best way to customize json responses (rabl, acts_as_api ...) ?
2. What's the best way to respond with different json representations for a single entity ? 
   for example: for a given entity Cat with "name", "age" and "birth_day" i want to respond with `{ "name":"joe", "age":"3" }` for *iphone api users* and with `{ "name":"joe", "age":3", "birth_day":"1/1/2009" }` for *all other api users*.

Thanks !

Comment: +1 for Rabl. It rocks and makes the case mentioned in the second question possible as well. Your question however is hard to "answer" since you're looking for opinions rather than an actual solution to a problem.

Comment: I'm not looking for opinions, i'm looking for the best practice. Do you have any example of how to do (2) in rabl ?

Comment: That's a thin line :D — How do you separate between the responses? Are you using different controllers or are you splitting within one controller action?

Comment: That's what i'm asking ... what's the best way to do this ? Maybe there's a 3rd party plugin that does it for you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for whom it may concern... my solution:

acts_as_api is the rails plugin i used.

i also added a mime type for iphone and in my controllers i used "respond_to" to answer with the correct json template.